# How to define inline getter with this pattern?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to move the Equity property inline and having trouble with the syntax. What is the correct way to define inline getter properties with this pattern?

```js
Account = function() {
  var Number;
  var Cash;
  var MTMPL;

  function Account(number, cash, mtmpl) {
    this.Number = number;
    this.Cash = cash;
    this.MTMPL = mtmpl;
  };

  // How to define the Equity property inline?  
  Account.prototype.Equity = {
    get: function() {
      return this.Cash + this.MTMPL;
    }
  }

  return Account;
}();

var account = new Account("123", 100, 50);

/*
Object.defineProperties(Account.prototype, {
Equity : {
        get : function() {
            return this.Cash + this.MTMPL;
        }
    }
});*/

alert(account.Equity);
```

Comment: (Opinion) You don't it makes it harder to read. Also this is primarily opinion based, you can code how ever works best for you and your team.

Comment: I didn't do much, but just some cleanup and removed unnecessary code and [here is the result](http://ideone.com/adWJWL)

Answer (score 2):

Within the `Account` constructor:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'Equity', {
    get: function() { return this.Cash + this.MTMPL; }
});
```

Even though, to be honest, it's not clear what you are trying to do above.

Comment: @ddrjca: Add the definition for the equity field to the constructor of the Account object. Also, fields for OOP should be lowercase to reduce confusion between class/object type names. http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/9onh5kyh/

Comment: Does this particular pattern have a name ?   It would be helpful to know for when I research future questions. The way I defined the Account object.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with this?

```
Account =  function () {
    var Number;
    var Cash;
    var MTMPL;

    function Account(number,cash,mtmpl) {
        this.Number = number;
        this.Cash = cash;
        this.MTMPL = mtmpl;
    };

    Object.defineProperties(Account.prototype, {
        Equity : {
            get : function() {
                return this.Cash + this.MTMPL;
            }
        }
    });
    return Account;
}();
var account = new Account("123",100,50);
alert(account.Equity);
```